# Replace part of a formula in range between values

Tags: excel, vba

using VBA

How can I systematically find all number values in a range of formulas that are between 500 and 1500 and replace them with, say, 1500?

The formulas are not all the same

Example:

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(Data!$B$2:$B$1490, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A27,Data!$B$2:$B$1120)*COUNTIF($U$25,Data!$D$2:$D$1231), ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$1123)-MIN(ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$789))+1, ""), ROW($A1)))),#N/A)
```

And I want it to look like:

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(Data!$B$2:$B$1500, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A27,Data!$B$2:$B$1500)*COUNTIF($U$25,Data!$D$2:$D$1500), ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$1500)-MIN(ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$1500))+1, ""), ROW($A1)))),#N/A)
```

From range A2:Z500.

```
Cell.Formula = Replace(Cell.Formula, "1000", "1500")
```

Can do single replacements, but how can I utilize it for a criteria?

Appreciate any tips

Comment: `range("A2:Z500").Replace 1000,1500`

Comment: No way! It looks like I was way overthinking this, I will attempt your solution now Scott, thank you always for the prompt response.

Comment: Hi Scott, this finds all 1000 and replaces it with 1500, is there a way to find all values based on criteria like I listed in the question?

Comment: Not without looping.